# User need to click on save button twice if flatlist is inside scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have placed Flatlist and save button inside scrollview and each Flatlist item has a input field.
When the input field is in focus and keyboard is open.
When I touch the save button first time it is dismissing the keyboard and next time when the user clicks on button action is performed.

I have tried adding keyboardShouldPersistTaps ={'handled'}
In scrollview and flatlist.

But it is not working.

Please find my pseudo code below.

```
   <Scrollview>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   <View>
   <Flatlist/>
   <TouchableOpacity>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   </Scrollview>
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this props in your Scrollview Component,

keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'

Comment: example <Scrollview {props}> </Scrollview>

Comment: Hi @AKAK
Thanks for your reply.
I have tried this but not working.